# Why does Datastax's JAVA driver needs access to all the servers in the cluster even in multi DC setup

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Datastax's JAVA driver needs to have access to all the servers in the cluster even in a multi DC set up. This seems to be a problem when we want to localise the queries. Is there a way to do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the LoadBalancingPolicy that you use.  [By default](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/Policies.html#defaultLoadBalancingPolicy()) the driver uses a DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy with Token awareness and chooses to connect to no hosts in remote datacenters, but chooses which datacenter is local based on your contact points.

You can [configure a DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.html#DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(java.lang.String,%20int)) to explicitly specify the local datacenter and that you want to connect to 0 hosts in remote DCs, i.e.:

```java
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
    .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy("mydc", 0)))
    .build();
```

Note that the wrapping TokenAwarePolicy is not required, but it is a nice to have to have the driver choose coordinators that own data that you are storing/querying for handling requests.